# How to use unique Kafka topic for each test run

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

When writing integration tests for my spring integration application which relies on Kafka as message source I often encounter the problem to create a clean test state between two test cases because the IntegrationFlow is configured to consume from a topic which I need to utilize in the tests. Doesn't matter if I use TestContainers or EmbeddedKafka, for both the best practice is to use a unique topic for a single test.

Anyway, I don't know how to re-initialize the IntegrationFlow with a new topic between two tests.

Imagine

```java
    @Bean
    public StandardIntegrationFlow startKafkaInbound() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(Kafka
                .messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                        kafkaConsumerFactory,
                        ListenerMode.record,
                        serviceProperties.getImportTopic().getName())
                .messageConverter(messagingMessageConverter)
                .errorChannel(Objects.requireNonNull(errorHandler.getInputChannel()))
                .autoStartup(false)
        )
                .channel(Objects.requireNonNull(routeKafkaMessage().getInputChannel()))
                .get();
    }
```

Now when writing IntegrationTests, how to re-subscribe this flow to a different topic?

Best regards
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know what is your `serviceProperties.getImportTopic()`, but feel like this is the place where you could manipulate the topic name between tests and after flow stopping/starting.

For better understanding what exactly is the problem with that, we might need to see what you are doing in your tests.

**UPDATE**

Yes, you are right: the topics are provided to the underlying `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` from that `Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter` during creating. You cannot modify its state at runtime without reflection. In your test you stop this channel adapter. Use `TestUtils.(messageDrivenChannelAdapter, "messageListenerContainer", ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.class)`.
Call its `getContainerProperties()`. Then `DirectFieldAccessor` to set the `ContainerProperties.topics` field into a desired random value. Then you start that `messageDrivenChannelAdapter`. The `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` creates child containers in its `start()` and populate the container properties for them.

Comment: Just assume it's a basic configuration property. Changing that does not have any effect, as the value is read when creating that flow, starting and stopping only Works on that config value.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. Updated my answer. It is probably not what you would expect, but there is indeed no other way to modify topics on the fly.